# Real Time Search in django Rendered Templetes

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-templates

Project Details:-

1. template is rendered by using pagination in django view .
2. I used for loop in Templete (only for tr that contains td ) to display all results within the html table.
3. Pagination Logic is added to templete below the table tag.
4. There are various columns in table .

I want to Implement Real Time Search Functionlty to a table Rendered by django.
Also , search should me made from all pages. And Only that entries should be shown which contains that string fron search box.

Comment: You'll have to change how the table is presented, if you're using pagination in the view then you'll have to reload the page every time you change page, what you want is to load the view with an empty table and then load the data using AJAX, THEN with that endpoint to load data you can add filters and pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML :-

```
<input type="search" name="search" id="search_box" placeholder="Search Using Saral-ID or Name">
```

Django-View :

```
def search_form(request):
    pk = request.GET.get('id')
    filter_data = br_ambedkar_form.objects.filter(saral_id__contains=str(pk)) | br_ambedkar_form.objects.filter(applicant_name__contains=str(pk))
    return render(request , 'br_ambedkar_forms/search_table/search_table.html' , {
        'forms' : filter_data,
    })
```

Javascript:-

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' , ()=>{
    document.getElementById('search_box').addEventListener("keyup" , ()=>{
        search_value = document.getElementById('search_box').value;
        fetch(`/forms/search/?id=${search_value}`)
        .then(data => data.text())
        .then(text => {
            document.getElementById('table').innerHTML=text
        });
    })  
})
```

This Way I am able get real time Search.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using htmx in a pretty straight forward way.
3 steps to follow:

- Extract your table in a separate file and include it in the page using django's include template tag.
- In your view check if the request is made by HTMX or by django (there is a django-htmx package that does it for you) and render either only the table with items in it or the entire page accordingly.
- Modify your search input to use htmx and submit the changes with ajax to your view.

In [this repository](https://github.com/halitcelik/django-htmx-beer-store/blob/main/django_htmx_example/beers/templates/beers/active-search.html) there is a working example of this using django-htmx.

There, it is done following these steps:
Step 1 (in your template)

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
                <div id="beers-table">
                    {% include "beers/includes/beers-table.html" %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Step 2 (In your view)

```py
def active_search(request):
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    page = request.GET.get("p", 1)
    template = "beers/active-search.html"
    if request.htmx:
        template = "beers/includes/beers-table.html"
    if query:
        beers = Beer.objects.search(query)
    else:
        beers = Beer.objects.all().prefetch_related("style", "category")
    return render(
        request,
        template,
        {
            "beers": Paginator(beers, 10).get_page(page),
            "page": page,
            "query": query,
            "not_found": not beers.exists(),
        },
    )
```

Step 3 (Your search form)

```
<form action="{% url 'beers:active-search' %}" method="get" class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label class="control-label">
        Search
        <img class="htmx-indicator" id="indicator"  src="{% static 'img/indicator.svg' %}">
    </label>
    <input 
        placeholder="Begin Typing To Search..." 
        data-hx-get="{% url 'beers:active-search' %}" 
        data-hx-trigger="keyup[target.value.length > 3 || target.value.length === 0] changed delay:500ms" 
        data-hx-target="#beers-table"
        data-hx-push-url="true"
        data-hx-indicator="#indicator"
        style="background:#fafafa" 
        class="form-control" 
        type="text"
        value="{{query|default:''}}"
        name="q" />
</form>
```